# 95 Integra Power hiccups

Tags: power, acura, integra

A 95 Integra has had recent cooling problems corrected (new radiator \ water pump) and is now experience 'hiccups': momentary drops in power during acceleration of the vehicle between 2-3K RPMs.  Hiccups cause a momentary loss in power that result in the vehicle jerking.  The problem was very minor and started after the radiator was installed and before the water pump was replaced.

Once at 3K or higher, this problem is non-existent.  Hiccups are NOT observed at idle or in steady state ops.  Hiccups are observed only when accelerating the vehicle speed and RPMS are between 2-3K.

I am planning to swap out the spark plugs in the hope that this inexpensive procedure will resolve the issue.  Given that at 3K RPMs or more there are no hiccups, can one conclude that the spark plugs are not the issue?

Is there a better systematic approach \ procedure to diagnosing root cause?    Suggestion are appreciated: thank you

## UPDATE

The sparked plugs were replaced and initial test results could not reproduce the hiccups.  The Acura fan-boys at the Advance Automotive inspected the plugs and they indicted that they were due to be changed.  Hopefully this is the last of problems for a while

Comment: Wadaya mean, "swap up the power?"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback: I'm tired and should not be posting.   Corrected the statement

Comment: You didn't say it, but is this a new problem after changing those items? Did it do it before? When you say "*hiccups*", are you referring to hesitation, jerking or just loss of power? Double check all the connectors and hoses. A major repair often requires many connections be broken. It could be as simple as a sensor being unplugged.

Comment: I have a 94 Integra GSR.  When the O2 sensor was bad, it would be completely gutless under about 3000 RPM, but run fine past that.  It should throw a code if your O2 is bad though.  Run the codes, reset the ECU.  Helps if you can use a scanner to read the sensors all at once.

Comment: @rpmerf: Advanced Auto indicates multiple manufacturers: which part is OEM?  Denso?

Comment: Not sure. NGK maybe?  I got a generic and soldered the wires.  Gone through 2 in the past couple 5 years / 50,000 miles though.